# Having trouble transferring a large (12GB) video from phone

Tags: iphone

I recorded a video yesterday in 4K on my iPhone 11.  I have two computers, a Windows 11 PC and a Macbook Pro from 2014 but running macOS 13.  Airdrop does not work on the Mac due to a faulty board the wifi card hooks into.  I do have an external USB dongle but it didn't seem to enable either Airdrop or Handoff (I also have a 2023 iPad), unless I set up something wrong.  Whenever I transfer the file over USB, it simply fails to transfer to the computer and I don't have the correct plug to connect it to the Macbook.  I'm currently copying it onto the iPad to see if the problem is in iOS 17.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into settings of my phone and changed the format of exported videos to "compatible".  This not only shrank the existing file form 12gb to 6, it also no longer failed on the USB transfer.  Apparently I've been having this problem with other videos I recorded in the past as well and this fixed them also.

Answer (score 1):

Besides AirDrop have you tried another method to move the file?

If it's already in Photos on your phone did you try to pull it from your synced Photos library on the MBP, PC, or via [iCloud Web](https://icloud.com)?

The Files app in iOS can copy files either into your iCloud shared folders, or to another shared folder on your network. On the Mac or PC you could share a folder via SMB and then browse to it and copy over the video. If you synced it to your iCloud directory you could also pull it down onto either laptop from iCloud directly.

Comment: file was too big to upload to icloud.

Comment: Sure, but if you want the full sized original, did you try a direct transfer?

Comment: I did.  It would not transfer over usb (as stated in the question) and what's really strange is it wouldn't transfer to the ipad over airdrop either.  It appeared to transfer but after the transfer was done, it simply wasn't there.